# Flatness and constancy of Hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb C$, and $f:X\to S$ a projective morphism. Let $F$ be a sheaf on $X$, and for a point $s\in S$ let us denote by $F_s=F\otimes_{\mathscr O_S}k(s)$ the induced sheaf on $X_s=f^{-1}(s)$.

> **Question**. Assume $F_s$ is supported in *dimension zero* for all $s\in S$, and $h^0(F_s)$ is *constant* on $S$. Is $F$ flat over $S$?

So, I think the answer would be yes if $S$ were reduced, as constancy of Hilbert polynomial and flatness are equivalent over a reduced base. But I was hoping that the *zero-dimensional* assumption could provide an example where one does not need reducedness to conclude that the constancy of the Hilbert polynomial implies flatness. Is this the case?

Would any more assumptions on the morphism $f$ be of any help? For example, if the family was projection from a product $X=Y\times S\to S$ with $Y$ a smooth variety (so $X_s\cong Y$ for all $s\in S$), could we say the answer is *yes* in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $X=Y\times S$ plays less of a role than the support of your sheaf $F$, which may not be of the form $Y\times S$. You can see thus a counterexample for both by the following. Take $S=k[\epsilon], \epsilon^2=0$, $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times S$ and $F=k$ supported at the origin of the line. $k$ is not flat over $k[\epsilon]$, but there is only one $s\in S$ and so your constancy is vacuous.